# Обновление поля таблицы с условием

Tags: sql, sql-server

Для каждого товара из таблицы Product установить скидку: если цена < 200, то скидка = 5%, иначе скидка = 7%. Вот так не работает:

```
UPDATE Product
SET Price = CASE
               WHEN Price < 200 THEN Price * 0.95
               ELSE Price * 0.93
           END;
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: *И так тоже не работает* Или не так делаешь, как пишешь, или не туда смотришь. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4f7417d16c938a3dba6ab08b11b4e51

Comment: ошибка прилетает Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Product_INSERT_UPDATE, Line 6 [Batch Start Line 24]
Вложенный запрос вернул больше одного значения. Это запрещено, когда вложенный запрос следует после =, !=, <, <=, >, >= или используется в качестве выражения.

Comment: Обычное дело. Доупрощался - получил вопрос, неадекватно воспроизводящий реальную ситуацию. Показанный код **НЕ МОЖЕТ** вызвать такую ошибку. Да в нём вообще никаких вложенных запросов нет!

Comment: @Akina мб триггер (то есть не доупрощался, я а не все рассказал)

Comment: @teran А что есть выбрасывание деталей, сочтённых ненужными, как не упрощение? У него там вообще процедура, а не одиночный запрос.

Comment: @Akina я к тому, что мб была хранимка, а он из нее оставил только эту часть. а мб хранимка вызывается в триггере, а он в об этом не знает, например.

Comment: да, это был триггер.